# How do we configure webshare proxy with api key in scrapy and also make use of scrapy-proxy-pool?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have webshare proxy API; and would like to use it in a scrapy script.
Which all configuration changes I will need to make in my script files as well enable it to make use of scrapy-proxy-pool also.